# Countries that have unmanned and manned fighter teaming projects

Tags: fighter, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I have been wondering what countries currently have military programs related to teams of manned and unmanned fighter aircraft? For instance, I know that the US has several programs related to this such as the [Have Raider](https://www.lockheedmartin.com/en-us/capabilities/autonomous-unmanned-systems/unmanned-military-case-study-have-raider-demo.html), which was a demo, or more newer programs such as [skyborg](https://afresearchlab.com/technology/vanguards/successstories/skyborg), [digital century series](https://aviationweek.com/defense-space/aircraft-propulsion/digital-century-series-approach-may-live-usafs-autonomous-plans), or more prominently the [loyal wingman](https://www.boeing.com/features/innovation-quarterly/2021/11/boeings-loyal-wingman.page) project. However, I am not sure about other countries.

I appreciate any additional info on this.

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome.
Sorry, but I am inclined to close this. To answer it would be required to compile a list that would need constant work to be up-to-date. No single answer would suffice, unless we force people to only put their efforts in a single community wiki.

Comment: Who says that any answer here MUST be constantly kept up to date?

Comment: @MichaelHall what good is to the community an outdated answer?

Comment: @Federico, questions and answers are dated, information changes.  There are probably more than a few stale ones out there right now.  Any question or answer may be updated of course, but why shut one down because some information might change later, and it might not be updated as rapidly as you desire?  Just give it a chance man!

Comment: @MichaelHall it is not about giving it a chance, it is about keeping the site healthy. allowing mindless list questions is not productive in that sense. having outdated replies is also counterproductive.

Comment: Information accurate as of a certain date IS useful from a historical perspective.  After 1969 we didn’t purge all libraries of all references to a possible future moon landing. List questions is a different issue.  Glad that you just voted to close though, and restrained your moderator hammer.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-was-my-shopping-list-question-closed - this is our equivalent of a "shopping list" question, clearly its not asking to go shopping but it needs to be closed for the same reasons

Comment: @MichaelHall you have also just described why printed books have their limitations, and we are not limited in the same way.

Comment: @Federico seems like a valid question to me. There's only so many projects of such kind and only so many will begin in future. There's plenty of other questions that could use moderation.

Comment: @Mridul made my point.  I'm fine with following the rules here, it is the inconsistent application that is irksome.  Thoughtful, interesting and well written questions are often closed for some minor excursion from the guidelines, while very poor quality ones remain open.

Comment: @Jamiec, yes, I completely agree!  But closing a question before it is answered because it might require a future edit is attaching a limitation that wouldn't otherwise exist.

Comment: How about we edit to "what countries currently have..." so it's anchored in time and won't "require" updating if new projects start or old ones end years or decades in the future? Having approved a different edit, I can't edit that in, but maybe somebody else could. @MichaelHall - that work for you?

Comment: I did not expect my _mindless_ question would ignite such a discussion. I apologize for the problems associated with the problem. So, to confirm my understanding, to find the answer to such questions, either do the research on your own (which I have already done), create a wiki page and hope that others would contribute to it, or post it on reddit which has admittedly much lower quality of reply? Although as @Mridul mentioned, not many projects of interest exist in the first place.

Comment: @RalphJ, I had no objections before.  Because each question and answer is date stamped it should be easy to discern the relevance and accuracy at some future date.  In other words, I’m not the one who needs convincing!

Comment: Adding a date doesnt solve the problem! If we take it to it's absurd end we end up with "Countries which have ...... august 2023", "countries which have ..... feb 2027" ad infinitum. List questions do not fit well in our format. They never have.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, the [Tempest](https://www.airforce-technology.com/projects/tempest-future-combat-air-system-fcas-aircraft-uk/) aircraft is planned to enter service in 2035:

> The aircraft will support scalable autonomy, which will enable manned,
> unmanned and optionally manned operations.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BAE_Systems_Tempest), it's a "sixth generation" aircraft being developed by the "Team Tempest" consortium which includes the Ministry of Defence, BAE Systems, Rolls-Royce, Leonardo UK, and MBDA UK.  Italy, Sweden and Japan have shown interest in co-operating in the development of some parts of the system.

There is also a French/German/Spanish programme called the [Future Air Combat System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_Combat_Air_System):

> The FCAS will consist of a Next-Generation Weapon System (NGWS) as
> well as other air assets in the future operational battlespace.
> The NGWS's components will be remote carrier vehicles (swarming
> drones) as well as a New Generation Fighter (NGF) - a sixth-generation
> jet fighter that by around 2040 will replace current France's
> Rafales, Germany's Typhoons and Spain's EF-18 Hornets.

Turkey is developing [TAI TF-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TAI_TF-X) and the two-seat variant will use:

> the MUM-T (Manned Unmanned Teaming) capability of the TF-X with
> maximum efficiency. With the additional seat, the pilot in the back
> will be able to coordinate and manage drones like the Bayraktar
> Kizilelma & Bayraktar TB2.

An unmanned version of the proposed Russian [PAK DP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikoyan_PAK_DP#Design) fighter is under consideration.